# How to share image of imageview?

Tags: android, imageview, save, share

I have ImageView and I want to share its image.

Following is my code,

```
btshare.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

                 View content = findViewById(R.id.full_image_view);
                 content.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                     Bitmap bitmap = content.getDrawingCache();
                     File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                     File cachePath = new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + "/DCIM/Camera/image.jpg");
                     try 
                     {
                         root.createNewFile();
                         FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(root);
                         bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, ostream);
                         ostream.close();
                     } 
                     catch (Exception e) 
                     {
                         e.printStackTrace();
                     }


                 Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                 Uri phototUri = Uri.parse("/DCIM/Camera/image.jpg");
                 shareIntent.setData(phototUri);
                 shareIntent.setType("image/*");
                 shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, phototUri);
                 startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share Via"));

             }  



    });
```

when i press the button i get these errors ?

```
01-13 06:00:19.282: W/System.err(6199): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)
01-13 06:00:19.286: W/System.err(6199):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:409)
01-13 06:00:19.286: W/System.err(6199):     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:88)
01-13 06:00:19.294: W/System.err(6199):     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:73)
01-13 06:00:19.294: W/System.err(6199):     at com.safshari.mandegar.FullImageActivity$3.onClick(FullImageActivity.java:116)
01-13 06:00:19.294: W/System.err(6199):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
01-13 06:00:19.294: W/System.err(6199):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
01-13 06:00:19.298: W/System.err(6199):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
01-13 06:00:19.298: W/System.err(6199):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-13 06:00:19.298: W/System.err(6199):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-13 06:00:19.302: W/System.err(6199):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
01-13 06:00:19.302: W/System.err(6199):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-13 06:00:19.302: W/System.err(6199):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-13 06:00:19.302: W/System.err(6199):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
01-13 06:00:19.306: W/System.err(6199):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-13 06:00:19.306: W/System.err(6199):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-13 06:00:19.310: W/System.err(6199): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)
01-13 06:00:19.310: W/System.err(6199):     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
01-13 06:00:19.310: W/System.err(6199):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
01-13 06:00:19.310: W/System.err(6199):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:393)
01-13 06:00:19.314: W/System.err(6199):     ... 14 more
01-13 06:00:19.618: E/Genymotion(489): Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
```

what should I do and what permissions my program needs ? I have already declared following permissions,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Final Code so anyone can use to save and share image from imageview :

```
View content = findViewById(R.id.full_image_view);
                 content.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

                     Bitmap bitmap = content.getDrawingCache();
                     File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                     File cachePath = new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + "/DCIM/Camera/image.jpg");
                     try {
                         cachePath.createNewFile();
                         FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(cachePath);
                         bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, ostream);
                         ostream.close();
                     } catch (Exception e) {
                         e.printStackTrace();
                     }


                     Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                     share.setType("image/*");
                     share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(cachePath));
                     startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share,"Share via"));

             }
```

happy coding

Comment: Can I share from an image view and not from a file/url?

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work. I get:  java.io.IOException: No such file or directory.

Answer (score 5):

Try below code to share your image:

```
    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.setType("image/*");
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + "/DCIM/Camera/image.jpg"));
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share,"Share via"));
```

Add these permissions to `AndroidMenifest.xml`

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: why do i need camera permission ? @zanky

Comment: not working with these three permission and the code on top . via blutooth nothing happens and via other programs its says invalid file

Comment: also i have a warning on this line that says cachepath never used  File cachePath = new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + "/DCIM/Camera/image.jpg");

Comment: 01-13 10:32:44.381: D/AbsListView(12194): unregisterIRListener() is called 
01-13 10:32:45.066: D/AbsListView(12194): onDetachedFromWindow
01-13 10:32:45.066: D/AbsListView(12194): unregisterIRListener() is called @zanky

Comment: this code is working for me.Is your image really saved in device?

Comment: no i fixed the top part and now its saving but not sharing but the image is saving perfectly top part is :

Comment: `code` content.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            Bitmap bitmap = content.getDrawingCache();
            File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File cachePath = new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + "/DCIM/Camera/image.jpg");
            try {
                cachePath.createNewFile();
                FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(cachePath);
                bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, ostream);
                ostream.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
   }`code`

Comment: Ok..so now is it sharing image? And instead of writing working code in comment,edit your code in question with this code.It will help others.

Comment: This uses a local file path, not an ImageView.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add this permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 2):

try creating the cache to store this image first and then share it because you can only share images which are public to other applications also.You cannot share the content which are private to you application.

use Context.getExternalCacheDir() to create cache and then share the content of this cache

Answer (score 0):

```
Bundle intent = getIntent().getExtras();
cardView = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.card);
final String query = intent.getString("Query1");

db = new DataBaseHelper(Image.this);

Cursor c = db.getData(query);

if (c.getCount() != 0) {
    c.moveToFirst();

    do {
        image = c.getString(5);
        title=c.getString(3);
    } while (c.moveToNext());
}

txt.setText(title);

img.setImageDrawable(getResources()
    .getDrawable(getResources().getIdentifier(image, "drawable", getPackageName())));
```

Comment: how to share image through intent

Answer (score 0):

- get bitmap from imageview

```
imageview.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap image = mainimg.getDrawingCache();
```

- convert url

```
public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
  ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
  String path = Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
  return Uri.parse(path);
}
```

- then share button

```
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType("image/*");
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, getImageUri(this,getImageUri));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share,"Share via"));
```