# Share text and image at the same time in Android

Tags: java, android, image, text, share

I've been trying for several hours to share both text & image (*at the same time*) with `Intent.ACTION_SEND`. And despite all my attempts to make it work, I'm still not able to do it.

I've searched all over Google and it may be strange, but I only found 2 posts that talk about how to share text & image *at the same time*, I tried them out however none of them worked. I tried using a method and here's what I ended up with:

```
Uri imageToShare = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.application/drawable/invite"); //Image to be shared
String textToShare = "Text to be shared"; //Text to be shared

Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, textToShare);
shareIntent.setType("*/*");
shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, imageToShare);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share with"));
```

- The code above shows an error message **"Sharing failed, please try again."**
- The image I want to send is `invite.png` and it's located in the `drawable` folder.
- I'm using a phone with Android O (8.0).

I hope the above information will be useful. I'm still a beginner in Java and any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally managed to do it in a simpler way! I created a `base64` from the image and added it as a string in the `strings.xml` file *(make sure to remove `data:image/png;base64,` from the start of the string).*

The code I used is the following:

```
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(getString(R.string.share_image), Base64.DEFAULT); //The string is named share_image.
Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
Uri imageToShare = Uri.parse(MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(MainActivity.this.getContentResolver(), decodedByte, "Share image", null)); //MainActivity.this is the context in my app.
String textToShare = "Sample text"; //Text to be shared

Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType("image/*");
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, textToShare);
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageToShare);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share with"));
```

I hope this answer will solve many peoples issues!

Thanks a lot for @notyou & @CommonsWare

Answer (score 2):

First, there is no requirement for any app to support sharing both text and an image via `ACTION_SEND`.

Second, the `Uri` for the image goes in `EXTRA_STREAM` [as notyou pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48736774/115145).

Third, few apps will know how to handle `android.resource` as a `Uri` scheme. After all, that is not [the documented scheme for an `EXTRA_STREAM` `Uri`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_STREAM). It needs to be `content`, where you serve your content through a `ContentProvider`, such as `FileProvider`.

Fourth, you may have better luck if you specify the actual MIME type, rather than use the wildcard.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you help for the third one? The image is in the drawable folder.

Comment: @TouficBatache: I am unclear why the user would want to share a fixed image. Regardless, you will need to use some `ContentProvider`. For example, you might copy that image to a file on the device's filesystem (e.g., in `getCacheDir()`) and serve it up using `FileProvider`.

Comment: Do you think I can do it with the base64 form of the image? And the image is a promo image for the app ;)

Comment: @TouficBatache: "Do you think I can do it with the base64 form of the image?" -- I doubt that many other apps will know what to do with a base64 image.

Comment: What I meant is that I'd have a script to convert it to a bitmap uri... Is that possible?

Comment: @TouficBatache: I am uncertain what you mean by "a bitmap uri". If you mean a `data:` URL, I doubt that many apps will know what to do with one of those.

Comment: Hmm... Well, I'll try to figure it out by myself. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

This code will allow you to send any bitmap image with text.

```
Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.refer_app);
            Uri imageToShare = Uri.parse(MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), decodedByte, "Share app", null));   // in case of fragment use [context].getContentResolver()
            String shareMessage = "message to share";
            Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            share.setType("image/*");
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareMessage);
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageToShare);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share via"));
```

Comment: This works for me, but is there a way to prevent the photo I am trying to share being saved in my phone? As it stands, whenever I click share, a copy of the photo is saved locally.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
Intent iShare = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
iShare.setType("image/*");
iShare.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Your text”);
iShare.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Your image);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(iShare, "Choose app to share photo with!"));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is `Your image` a Uri?

Comment: Yes, it’s using Uri.fromFile

Comment: Ok, I tried your code with WhatsApp and it sent a blank _Untitled_ document.

Comment: Hmm it works for me (but it’s from a picture taken by the camera if that makes any difference).

Comment: Not sure about that... I'll try with another image and keep you updated.

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21095826/6722100 and just add the EXTRA_TEXT also.

Comment: Aha! It turns out the problem is from the image. Maybe I was getting the Uri wrong? I'll try to make it work.