# share intent for viewPager images

Tags: android, android-intent, android-viewpager, share

I have made image slider using `ViewPager` and **Picasso**. I have added XML for share button under it and I've also implemented `onclick` in it, but I don't know what to do after that.

I want to share the image when we press share button. Please help me. I'm not being able to do that.

In activity_main.xml, I have added viewpager and button named as share. Tts id is share_image.

This is main activity:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ViewPager viewPager;

    private int[] imageUrls = new int[]{
            R.raw.a,
            R.raw.b,
            R.raw.c //and many others
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        ViewPageAdapter adapter = new ViewPageAdapter(this, imageUrls);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
}
```

This viewPagerAdapter:

```java
public class ViewPageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private int[] imageUrls;

    ViewPageAdapter(Context context, int[] imageUrls) {
        this.context = context;
        this.imageUrls = imageUrls;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return imageUrls.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);

        Picasso.get()
                .load(imageUrls[position])
                .into(imageView);
        container.addView(imageView);
        return imageView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {
        container.removeView((View) object);
    }
}
```

Comment: could you add your `ViewPager` adapter code?

Comment: @Birju Vachhani Thank you for your suggestion. I really sorry for that. Now, I have added that. please help me. I dont know who down-voted the answer. :(. They could give me the chance to improve the answers, nah? like you suggest me to add more details. anyway, please help me with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ViewPager` Adapter:

```
public class ViewPageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private int[] imageUrls;
    public View currentImageView;

    ViewPageAdapter(Context context, int[] imageUrls) {
        this.context = context;
        this.imageUrls = imageUrls;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return imageUrls.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {
        ImageView view = new ImageView(context);

        Picasso.get()
                .load(imageUrls[position])
                .into(view);
        container.addView(view);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {
        container.removeView((View) object);
    }

    @Override
    public void setPrimaryItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        currentImageView = (View)object;
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ViewPager viewPager;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    private int[] imageUrls = new int[]{
            R.drawable.after_cookie,
            R.drawable.before_cookie,
            R.drawable.androidparty
    };
//    private WebBackForwardList viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progress);
        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        final ViewPageAdapter adapter = new ViewPageAdapter(this, imageUrls);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        ImageView NextButton = findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
        NextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(getItem(+1), true); //getItem(+1) for next
            }
        });

        ImageView PreviousButton = findViewById(R.id.btnPrevious);
        PreviousButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(getItem(-1), true);
            }
        });

        ImageView btnShare = findViewById(R.id.btnShare);
        btnShare.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (adapter.currentImageView == null) {
                    // Error: cannot get current image to share
                    return;
                }
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(adapter.currentImageView.getWidth(), adapter.currentImageView.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                adapter.currentImageView.draw(new Canvas(bitmap));
                Uri uri = saveImage(bitmap);
                shareImageUri(uri);
            }
        });
    }

    private void shareImageUri(Uri uri) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        intent.setType("image/png");
        startActivity(intent);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    private Uri saveImage(Bitmap image) {
        //TODO - Should be processed in another thread
        File imagesFolder = new File(getCacheDir(), "images");
        Uri uri = null;
        try {
            imagesFolder.mkdirs();
            File file = new File(imagesFolder, "shared_image.png");

            FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream);
            stream.flush();
            stream.close();
            uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "com.example.recyclerview_codelabs.fileprovider", file);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return uri;
    }

    private int getItem(int i) {
        return viewPager.getCurrentItem() + i;
    }
}
```

In your **activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/main_image"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:context="com.example.recyclerview_codelabs.ZoomableImageView" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btnShare"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_button"
        android:contentDescription="Share"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_share_black_24dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btnPrevious"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btnPrevious"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_button"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btnNext"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btnShare"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_media_previous" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btnNext"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btnDownload"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btnPrevious"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_media_next" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btnDownload"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_button"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btnNext"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/stat_sys_download" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        tools:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**file_paths.xml** in **res>xml** folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <cache-path name="shared_images" path="images/"/>
    </paths>
</resources>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.recyclerview_codelabs">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.example.recyclerview_codelabs.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: share button is not working, when I clicked share button app automatically closes. It was showing error in 'adapter' which is in share btn's onClick. Studio recommend me to make it final and error was gone but while running app it is not working. I made final in this way ```final ViewPageAdapter adapter = new ViewPageAdapter(this, imageUrls);```

Comment: `shareBtn` needs to be replaced with your share button view.

Comment: yes, i did that; ImageView shareBtn = find... then shareBtn.setOnCLick... @BirjuVachhani sir please help me please

Comment: this is my project  https://drive.google.com/file/d/11dxO9AVO15MOWkAMnPXEKriwVJ_VFPhh/view?usp=sharing please help me @BirjuVachhani sir?

Comment: In your code, I see that there's no share button. I updated my answer @Rajana

Comment: I tried exactly what you said, but it is showing error. I also tried other method, it is not working. please see this. this is uptated one. https://drive.google.com/open?id=15eEcvI1pyEMXoFLHdlgnTybQLZHTdiHe please solve this and help @BirjuVachhani  sir? I'll always pray you .

Comment: @Rajana I looked into your code and fixed it. It is working now. Check my updated answer and replace your code with it. It will work

Comment: I shared one image and it is sharing another image. @BirjuVachhani ??

Comment: please look this video https://drive.google.com/open?id=1pURnskEF2cO0gCdSOMkIP9VjoifRz2Km it is not sharing image of 2nd position?

Comment: please look this screenrecorded video  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pURnskEF2cO0gCdSOMkIP9VjoifRz2Km/view  @BirjuVachhani

Comment: I updated `ViewPagerAdapter` code in my answer. Please replace your code with it and  check. Don't forget to upvote it and mark it as correct answer if it works. @Dibas

Comment: thank you very much @BirjuVachhani it worked. Now, to add 'download' feature all are same but we should replace share intent with 'download' ?? yes?? okay, i'll try. please dont be angry

Comment: hi sir. please help me with this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57275501/download-option-in-image-by-viewpager you can only easily help me to tackle this, please @BirjuVachhani sir, I need your help. i searched at many place, tried to do as of share one, but i cant succed :(

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no code for ViewPager slides i will have to assume that you are showing your images in an ImageView. Let's say that that ImageView has an id picture_view.

And when you reference it in your slide view (Fragment or a ViewGroup) you reference it as:

```
ImageView pictureView = findViewById(R.id.picture_view)
```

In order to share it you will have to do 2 things:

1. To share an image you will have to save it locally.

You will need to get Bitmap from your imageView.

```
Bitmap bmp = ((BitmapDrawable) pictureView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```

Create a new file.

Then you will need to write a compressed version of the bitmap to an outputStream.

```
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
            out.close();
```

And finally get image uri using:

```
// NOTE: authority here should match authority in manifest declaration
Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context,
                    "authority",
                    file);
```

2. In order to use the saved image in your implicit intent you will need to provide 
   a Uri for it. Let's use the photoURI.

   intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, photoURI);

Let me know if you still can't figure it out and i will help.

Comment: Hi @Alex, thank you for your suggestion. I really appreciate this, But, it is not working. It was my fault that, i didn't add codes. please forgave me. I'm beginner. Please help me with this??

Comment: Since you are a beginner try visiting https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21084866/how-to-share-image-of-imageview and look at Soheyl answer. I think it will be easier to understand even tho it uses some deprecated functions.

Comment: Ive made image slider of many images by viewPager, it is not tracking my images of slider. Please help me @Alex

Comment: So your share button is outside (over) ViewPager?

Comment: Yes in mainactivity.xml there is viewpager and under it Ive made share button.

Comment: Birju Vachhani answer seems like it could solve your issue, let me know if there is anything else.

Comment: Birju's method is not working. While clickingin share btn app crashes. :( please help me

Comment: please help me, please? this is my project https://drive.google.com/file/u/1/d/15eEcvI1pyEMXoFLHdlgnTybQLZHTdiHe/view @Alex please

Answer (score -1):

If your button is set up well you can add this code in the OnClick method,

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sharingIntent.setType("image/*");
sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imagePath);

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share Image via"));
```

Create intent to share 
Set the sharing type, how it is to be shared
Create the item to be shared if had not done that
Parse the subject to be shared to the created intent
Parse the body of message to be shared
Give the user a chance to decide means to share,
    //intent.createChooser

Comment: That is not how you share images via a share intent.

Comment: it is not tracking the position of image