# putExtra(): None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied

Tags: android, kotlin

I got a few errors when i tried to use intent to use share function.

I just have an simple app, where i show an image on that page, where i want to use the share button to share this image.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    // cropped image
    croppedImageView = findViewById(R.id.cropped_image_view)

    shareBtn = findViewById(R.id.shareBtn)
    shareBtn.setOnClickListener {
        val intent= Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
        //intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Hey Check out this Great app:")
        //intent.type="text/plain"
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, croppedImageView)
        intent.type = "application/pdf"
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, null))
    }

    // start document scan
    documentScanner.startScan()
}
```

Thats all...
Its from this git: https://github.com/WebsiteBeaver/android-document-scanner

But i wanted to add share button to share  this pdf/jpg.

What i added is just the block with ShareBtn. But i get this errors:

```
None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied: 
public open fun putExtra(p0: String!, p1: Bundle?): Intent defined in android.content.Intent
public open fun putExtra(p0: String!, p1: Parcelable?): Intent defined in android.content.Intent
public open fun putExtra(p0: String!, p1: Serializable?): Intent defined in android.content.Intent
public open fun putExtra(p0: String!, p1: Array<(out) Parcelable!>?): Intent defined in android.content.Intent
public open fun putExtra(p0: String!, p1: Array<(out) CharSequence!>?): Intent defined in android.content.Intent
public open fun putExtra(p0: String!, p1: Array<(out) String!>?): Intent defined in android.content.Intent
public open fun putExtra(p0: String!, p1: Boolean): Intent defined in android.content.Intent
public open fun putExtra(p0: String!, p1: BooleanArray?): Intent defined in android.content.Intent
public open fun putExtra(p0: String!, p1: Byte): Intent defined in android.content.Intent
public open fun putExtra(p0: String!, p1: ByteArray?): Intent defined in android.content.Intent
public open fun putExtra(p0: String!, p1: Char): Intent defined in android.content.Intent
public open fun putExtra(p0: String!, p1: CharArray?): Intent defined in android.content.Intent
public open fun putExtra(p0: String!, p1: CharSequence?): Intent defined in android.content.Intent
public open fun putExtra(p0: String!, p1: Double): Intent defined in android.content.Intent
public open fun putExtra(p0: String!, p1: DoubleArray?): Intent defined in android.content.Intent
public open fun putExtra(p0: String!, p1: Float): Intent defined in android.content.Intent
public open fun putExtra(p0: String!, p1: FloatArray?): Intent defined in android.content.Intent
public open fun putExtra(p0: String!, p1: Int): Intent defined in android.content.Intent
public open fun putExtra(p0: String!, p1: IntArray?): Intent defined in android.content.Intent
public open fun putExtra(p0: String!, p1: Long): Intent defined in android.content.Intent
public open fun putExtra(p0: String!, p1: LongArray?): Intent defined in android.content.Intent
public open fun putExtra(p0: String!, p1: Short): Intent defined in android.content.Intent
public open fun putExtra(p0: String!, p1: ShortArray?): Intent defined in android.content.Intent
public open fun putExtra(p0: String!, p1: String?): Intent defined in android.content.Intent
```

Can someone help me? I am new at this and doesnt find the problem :/

Comment: The error is telling you that you can't add an ImageView to an Intent. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to share the whole `ImageView` aka `croppedImageView` which is a View and cannot be stored in Android's `Intent` `Bundle`.

While you should convert it to `bitmap` and get it's original `Uri` first.

My suggestion that you can do a more simple approach by storing the `Uri` from `croppedImageResults` callback from [Android Document Scanner](https://github.com/WebsiteBeaver/android-document-scanner) directly as a Kotlin property and use it when trying to share (let me know if you need further explanation here)

If you want to sharing the image from the ImageView itself then Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60926500/4614550) will fix your issue.

Try this

```kotlin
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        // cropped image
        croppedImageView = findViewById(R.id.cropped_image_view)

        shareBtn = findViewById(R.id.shareBtn)
        shareBtn.setOnClickListener {
            val imageToShare: Bitmap = croppedImageView.buildDrawingCache()
            val share = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
            share.setType("image/*")
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, getImageUri(this, imageToShare))
            androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.startActivity(
                Intent.createChooser(
                    share,
                    "Share via"
                )
            )

        }

        // start document scan
        documentScanner.startScan()
    }
fun getImageUri(context: Context, image: Bitmap): Uri? {
        val bytes = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes)
        val path: String =
            Images.Media.insertImage(context.getContentResolver(), image, "Title", null)
        return Uri.parse(path)
    }
```

Comment: I've got error `Unresolved reference: Bitmap`

Comment: Did you import the Bitmap class ? 
Add  `import android.graphics.Bitmap` to your file imports